# Compare 2 objects and remove/add keys to object B

Tags: javascript, object, structure

I'm trying to compare the structure of 2 objects (recursively/nested).

Object's A structure should shape the structure of object B.

***`If they key exist in both objects, keep the existing key value in object B.`***

If **object B** does not contain a certain key that **object A** contains, it should be added with its value.
If **object B** contains a key that **object A** does not, it should be removed from **object B**.

I have found several code snippets that compares structures but creates a new object with the missing key/values, but what I'm trying to achieve is to actually change the structure of the **object B**  by adding missing key/values or removing keys that shouldn't be there.

```
  objA: {
    object1: {
      key1: "key1",
    },

    addObject2: {
      key1: "key1",
      key2: "key2",
      subObj1: {
        sub1: "sub1",
      },
    },
  },

  objB: {
    object1: {
      key1: "key1",
      key2: "key2",
    },
  },
```

*Structural changes*

- objA.addObject2 should be added to objB.
- objB.Object1.key2 should be removed from objB

Desired outcome

```
 objB: {
    object1: {
      key1: "key1",
    },

    addObject2: {
      key1: "key1",
      key2: "key2",
      subObj1: {
        sub1: "sub1",
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Please add some samples of input and the expected output. It's hard to imagine the desired behavior with just description.

Comment: @adiga I added more info, thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: What should happen if both have a key, but different values on it?

Comment: @OskarGrosser great question, they key value shouldn't change, it should remain as it is.

Comment: To be precise, in your example shown above, you not only look for keys in the objects themselves, but also in nested objects. Is that what you had in mind? If so, then your explanation of what you want is vague.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be as follows:

1. Add all unknown properties of A to B
2. Remove all unknown properties of B from B

This doesn't touch the already existing properties of B, and will modify B so that it is fitted to A.

Using named function expressions, doing the recursive part to look into nested objects becomes easy.

```js
function modifyObject(object, template) {
  (function addFromTemplate(obj, temp) {
    for (var prop in temp) {
      if (!(prop in obj))
        obj[prop] = temp[prop]; // Unknown to `obj`! Add it
      else if (typeof obj[prop] == 'object' && typeof temp[prop] == 'object')
        addFromTemplate(obj[prop], temp[prop]); // Nested objects! Recursion-step
    }
  })(object, template); // Start adding to `object` from `template`
  
  (function removeFromObject(obj, temp) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if (!(prop in temp))
        delete obj[prop]; // Unknown to `temp`! Remove it
      else if (typeof obj[prop] == 'object' && typeof temp[prop] == 'object')
        removeFromObject(obj[prop], temp[prop]); // Nested objects! Recursion-step
    }
  })(object, template); // Start removing properties of `object`
}

var a = {
  object1: {
    key1: 'key1',
  },
  addObject2: {
    key1: 'key1',
    key2: 'key2',
    subObj1: {
      sub1: 'sub1',
    }
  }
};

var b = {
  object1: {
    key1: 'key1',
    key2: 'key2',
  }
};

modifyObject(b, a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: This one works perfectly! thanks a bunch :D

Answer (score 1):

This is the recursive code and updates to the existing object

```js
function objectIterator(baseObject, extObject) {
for (const key in extObject) {
    if(!(key in baseObject)) {
        delete extObject[key];
    }
}

for (const key in baseObject) {
    if (Array.isArray(baseObject[key])) {
        extObject[key] = baseObject[key];
        if(extObject) {
            extObject[key] = arrayIterator(baseObject[key], extObject[key]);
        }
    }
    else if (typeof (baseObject[key]) == 'object') {
        extObject[key] = baseObject[key];
        if(extObject) {
            extObject[key] = objectIterator(baseObject[key], extObject[key]);
        }
    }
    else {
        extObject[key] = extObject ? extObject[key] || baseObject[key] : baseObject[key];
    }
}

return extObject;
}

function arrayIterator(baseArray, extArray) {
const responseArray = [];
for (let idx = 0; idx < extArray.length; idx++) {
    responseArray[idx] = objectIterator(baseArray[0], extArray[idx]);
}
return responseArray;
}

objectA = {
  "object1": {
    "key1": "key1"
  },
  "addObject2": {
    "key1": "key1",
    "key2": "key2",
    "subObj1": {
      "sub1": "sub1"
    }
  }
}

objectB = {
  "object1": {
    "key1": "key1",
    "key2": "key2",
    "subObj1": {
      "sub1": "sub1"
    }
  },
  "object3": {
    "key1": "key1",
    "key2": "key2",
    "subObj1": {
      "sub1": "sub1"
    }
  },
}

objectIterator(objectA, objectB);
console.log(objectB)
```

Comment: this does it! thanks so much, I've been scratching my head with this for a while. double thumbs up!

Comment: Actually, it was asked to modify an already existing object, not create a new one based on two others.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I have modified my answer now it updates in the existing object

Comment: objectB = objectIterator(objectA, objectB);

Comment: @SantiagoA.DeHeza That wouldn't have changed the actual object itself, it would have only updated the reference that specific variable has pointed to. If another variable would have a reference to the original object, it would _not_ point to the now-modified version of it, if the function would only return a new object.

Comment: the updated answer updates to the existing object instead of creating new object

Comment: Yes, I saw and upvoted it already. I only explained why the assignment with the un-edited version would not satisfy the actual question.

Comment: the way the code is now, if I were to add a new object to objectB that does not exist in the structure of objectA, that key in objectB won't be erased as it should.

Comment: @SantiagoA.DeHeza I have updated my answer

Comment: Actually, you are still overriding nested objects. Say, `a` is `{sub: {}}`, and `b` is `{sub: {}}`, and `bs` is `b.sub`, then when using your function, `b.sub` will not be `bs`, as it isn't the same object since it is overriden. What you would need to do instead is to only assign properties of `a` to `b` _iff_ (means "if and only if") `b` doesn't have them from the beginning, otherwise enter recursion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [deep-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff) that gives you a full deep diff between two objects. You can make decisions on which kind of operations should be reflected.

```js
const observableDiff = require('deep-diff').observableDiff;
const applyChange = require('deep-diff').applyChange;

let objA = {
  object1: {
    key1: 'key1'
  },
  addObject2: {
    key1: 'key1',
    key2: 'key2',
    subObj1: {
      sub1: 'sub1'
    }
  }
};
let objB = {
  object1: {
    key1: 'key1',
    key2: 'key2'
  }
};
 
observableDiff(objB, objA, function (d) {
  applyChange(objB, objA, d);
});
```